# Quiero crear un Navbar

Tags: css, navbar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hola a todos estoy aprendiendo CSS y quería probar hacer una navbar mas o menos como la imagen
El problema es que nose como hacer un corte diagonal

---

Ahorita llevo esto`

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            
                
               
                <li class="nav-item  mr-4 ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Nosotros</a>
                </li>
                 
                <li class="nav-item  mr-4">
                  <a class="nav-link " href="#Equipo">Equipo</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item  mr-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contactanos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item  mr-4">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#Portafolio">Portafolio</a>
                </li>

            </ul>`
```

---

Answer (score 0):

No se si estas usando `Bootstrap`, pero acá te dejo un ejemplo que como lo haría yo, aclaro no hay nada de `Bootstrap` en mi código, puede ser que cuando lo integres te cambien algunas cosas, por eso vas a tener que ir ajustando.

```css
.container {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto; }
    .container-header-navbar {
        background: #3F47CC
    }
    .logo-container {
        color: #fff;
        border-left: 80px solid transparent;
        border-top: 80px solid #000001;
        position: relative;
    }
    #logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: -60px;
        left: 50px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    nav {
        color: #fff;
        border-left: 80px solid transparent;
        border-top: 80px solid #3F47CC;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 80px;
    }
    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: -60px;
        left: 0;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;

    }
    nav ul li a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 30px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container-header-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <a href="" id="logo">NAVBAR</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Equipo">Equipo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contactanos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Portafolio">Portafolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>  
</header>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, suerte!